# Probability in higher dimension

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, geometric-probability

There are $n$ non negative numbers $x_i<1$. It is given that $S_1=\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i=1$. What is the probability that $$S_2=\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i^2<c$$ where $\frac1n<c<1$. 
Assume that each $x_i$ is uniformly distributed. 
Now I tried looking at this problem in terms of integrals:
$$P(squares|sum)=\frac{P(squares \cap sum)}{P(sum)}=\frac{something}{\int^1_0\int^{1-x_n}_0\int_0^{1-x_3-x_4-...-x_{n}}...\int_0^{1-x_2-x_3-...-x_{n}} dx_1dx_2...dx_{n-1}dx_n}$$
Now for the numerator, if we substitute the constraint in the inequality, we get $$S_2+(1-S_1)^2=c$$
Now how to get the numerator integral, I'm not quite sure. 
Also, is there any better, more elegant way of doing this problem? (I thought of using vectors, where the problem can be written as: $\vec x.\vec 1=1$ then $P(||\vec x||<\sqrt{c})=?$. But then we would have to model the distribution of $||\vec x||$ which I have no idea about) 
Or maybe a more direct approach? Like the ratio of areas (or volumes?), I somehow feel that in the denominator, there would be $V_{n-1}(\sqrt{c-\frac1n})$ where $V_{n-1}(r)$ is the hypervolume of $(n-1)$ ball of radius $r$.

Comment: If you're conditioning on $S_1 = 1$ exactly (as opposed to $S_1 \le 1$) then the denominator probability is zero.  In that case I _think_ you might be looking at the [symmetric Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) but I know nothing about it beyond the name & the wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the following naive and non-rigorous approach based on low-dimensional geometric analogues.

The required probability is a relation $\tfrac{V_1}{V_2}$ of two $(n-1)$-dimensional volumes. Namely, $V_2$ is a volume of $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex $S$ in $\Bbb R^n$ with vertices $e_1,\dots, e_n$, where for each $i$, the vector $e_i$ has $i$-th coordinate equal to $1$ and other coordinates equal to zero; $V_1$ is a volume of the intersection of $S$ with a ball $B$ of radius $\sqrt{c}$,
centered at the origin $(0,\dots, 0)$ of $\Bbb R^n$.

Since $S$ is a regular simplex with side $a=\sqrt{2}$, $V_2=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n-1)!} $ see, for instance, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume). The set $S\cap B$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional ball of radius $\sqrt{c-\tfrac 1n}$, centered at $(1/n,\dots 1,n)$, so $$V_1=\frac {\left(\pi(c-\tfrac 1n)\right)^{\tfrac{n-1}2}} {\Gamma\left(\tfrac{n+1}2\right)}.$$

Thus $$\frac{V_1}{V_2}=\frac {\left(\pi(c-\tfrac 1n)\right)^{\tfrac{n-1}2}(n-1)!} {\Gamma\left(\tfrac{n+1}2\right) \sqrt{n}}.$$